# SSH connection works, but not ansible connection

Tags: ansible, connection, openssh

I am trying to setup an ansible environment. The controlling server is a windows 10 machine. Therefore a cygwin was installed there. The server that are maintenanced/controlled are either windows 10 or linux machines.
For connection I could already setup a ssh connection. Therefore a openssh server was installed on the controlling server and a openssh client on the maintenanced/controller server. SSH keys (public, private) were generated and the public key transfered to the maintenanced/controlled server in the folder ssha/.ssh.
On cygwin a connection can be established. But when ansible is used I get an error. For the connection As a first step I have a simple ping and to keep it easy the host file and any playbook were both avoided. , e.g.

**ansible 192.168.1.30 -u ssha -m win_ping**

and the following message is then displayed.

**192.168.1.30 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Authentication or permission failure. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in "/tmp". Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p "`echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1610305300.3137856-64003402380126`" && echo ansible-tmp-1610305300.3137856-64003402380126="`echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1610305300.3137856-64003402380126`" ), exited with result 1",
    "unreachable": true
}**

I don't have any more ideas how to solve this issue. Your help is very much appreciated.

Hadrian

Comment: are you able to manually login to the remote node and create a file in `/tmp` directory? would you try this. if you see the failures, you might need to consider using `remote_tmp` variable to point to the remote user's home dir.

Comment: Where is the  /tmp directory on the window system? I mean for Linux it is clear (/tmp), However, on a windows system I would expect something like C:\...

Comment: well,  I didn't thought the remote to be windows.  your error message says there is some issues while performing actions on `~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1610305300.3137856-64003402380126`

Comment: ok, I have locally typed in /tmp on my controlling server (cygwin) "touch test". Then there was a file created. Further there was already some content in /tmp

**$ ls
apt-cyg.proxy.207722214ff5801cca21636ce3b4c558  ssh-Mk8pL3V2gPNe  uscreens
apt-cyg.proxy.fbdf7d75c8626b7d3f089b80ebed0898  test**

It seems that the file test was created. And also in the ~./.ansible/tmp/ folder I can create files.